Unable to swap and Send
Im unable to swap and send my solana in phantom wallet now, 2 days ago i have signed up to one site which says he will airdrop Dady tate meme token if i register, as i sign up my $40 worth of sol disappear suddenly then, send 2.5 solana in my phantom wallet but im unable to perform any action with it now, i.e Swaping or sending tokens to another address, please help me its my hard earned money
Thanks, looking forward for quick respone.
